# Bitmap Object Constructors Blocking

Tags: c#, sockets, bitmap

In my opinion, when A Bitmap Object is create by `Stream(socket)`, constructor function wait for EOF something like socket.close(), socket.shutdown)

This is the source code

**Sender side**

```
Socket client_s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint serverEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 4567);
client_s.Connect(serverEP);
NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(client_s);
bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

**Reciever side**

```
clientSocket = listenSocket.Accept();
NetworkStream s = new NetworkStream(clientSocket); 
Bitmap slice_bmp = new Bitmap(s);
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawImage(slice_bmp,0,0);
```

Receiver side is blocked until closing socket or half-closing socket(sender's side)

I want to send Bitmap Object to somebody repeatly
As you know, connection overhead is not negligible
this function should be processed with one socket

Some people suggest using special letter for classification between objects (sending multiple object exploiting one socket)
However this solution makes source complex
I want to make source code simple as possible.

finally my questions are summarized as follow

1. How can i send bitmap object repeatedly with one socket not using special letter?
2. Also i want to make source simple as possible (keeping above source code)
3. Finally how can i send EOF to exiting construction function (reciever side)

Comment: Have you tried closing `NetworkStream` from the server after the `Save` method?  You also should be using `using` statements.

Comment: closing NetworkStream haven't release Receiver's blocking